# how to solve autoincrement column value in database?

Tags: mysql

In the table , the first field is primary and autoincrement fields, the inserted value rows should be like 1,2,3,4 ... etc  rows . But in my database table the rows are not display like that , The rows value display like 1,2,5,6,3,4,7...etc rows. How to solve this problem in my database table . Please help me .

Comment: its nothing just sort the table on that column and it will display correctly. While querying using SELECT, provide order by clause on that column and will work.

Comment: I don't know which query you are using. Simply you can use this query. SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY primary_coloum

Comment: is it possible to add values into table in ascending order ?

Comment: there is not a problem to display these values and i also use order by clause . But when i insert values into table that time it will insert ascending order . Is it Posible ?

Comment: i solved this problem . Thanks .